# Power BI DAX Avg of AVG

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want the results to show, for example:
AVG GROUP 1 takes the avg of the brand then avg's the group. So,

```
avg BRAND J = 8.4
avg BRAND K = 4.8
avg BRAND L = 4.9
```

AVG GROUP 1 would then = 6.03    NOT 6.6

This would then continue for all groups.

Thanks

DataTable

```
GROUP      BRAND       PERCENT CHANGE
GROUP 1    BRAND J     4.8%
GROUP 1    BRAND J     12.0%
GROUP 1    BRAND K     4.8%
GROUP 1    BRAND L     4.9%
GROUP 2    BRAND M     8.0%
GROUP 3    BRAND A     4.0%
GROUP 4    BRAND B     8.0%
GROUP 4    BRAND B     15.0%
GROUP 4    BRAND C     8.0%
GROUP 4    BRAND N     7.0%
GROUP 5    BRAND D     5.0%
GROUP 5    BRAND E     4.0%
GROUP 5    BRAND E     6.0%
GROUP 5    BRAND E     6.0%
```

Comment: RADO has a good solution, but I'm curious why do you want to do this? Why is the average of an average the preferable metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a measure:

```
Group Average =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Data,
        Data[Group],
        Data[Brand],
        "Brand Average", AVERAGE ( Data[Percent Change] )
    ),
    [Brand Average]
)
```

where "Data" is your table name.

Result:

[image]

More detailed result:

[image]

How it works: 
First, we summarize your data by Group and Brand, and calculate average per each. Then, we use AVERAGEX to iterate the summarized table, and calculate the average of the averages.

**Edit:**

To filter out groups with 1 brand, modify the measure:

```
Group Average =
AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE (
            Data,
            Data[Group],
            Data[Brand],
            "Brand Average", AVERAGE ( Data[Percent Change] ),
            "Brand Count", CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[BRAND]), ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[GROUP])),
IF([Brand Count] > 1, [Brand Average])
)
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Worked perfectly. Question - what if I only wanted to show groups that had over 1 brand? So group 2 and 3 wouldn't show up.